# Tezos Q&A will go public on Tuesday, February 19th

Tags: discussion

I will be out for a few days next week, so I wanted to pre-announce that this community has successfully completed your private beta and will open to the public early next week. Barring any technical delays, this site should be listed as a full Stack Exchange site on Tuesday, February 19th.

*Congratulations!*

Stack Exchange sets the bar of a "healthy" private beta at about 150+ question in their first three weeks. This community surpassed that milestone easily, approaching  about 200 questions as we open the doors to a public launch. This is a testament to the hard work and dedication this community has organized as far back as the original site proposal.

Congratulations and enjoy your site!

Comment: When are you going to put out the call for moderators? It seems over due.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.1.2 Yes, I'll get that out tomorrow. Weird scheduling this week threw off my calendar.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.1.2 Quick Update — Jon Ericson is going to initiate a **"pro tem election"** in the next week or two rather than having the Community Team pick your moderators from the "nomination" thread of the past. He's been experimenting with the election format and it's been working quite well compared to just having the SE staff pick your Moderators outright. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

**Congratulations every one of the Tezos Stack Exchange community the site went public today!**

This means:

- The site is now listed in the Stack Exchange hamburger menu which is in the top right corner of any site on the network and also in the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) list.
- The site's privilege reputation requirements has increased.
- You will be getting your community moderators soon to help look after the site.
- **But, most importantly the site is now open to search engines this means it can show up in the search results if someone is researching a Tezos topic or their Tezos related issues bringing more people to the community to learn, share their knowledge and help each other out!**